# Embedding a domain specific language in an OCaml toplevel -- to Camlp4 or not?

Tags: metaprogramming, ocaml, syntactic-sugar, ocamlyacc

I have some code that includes a `menhir`-based parser for a *domain*  *specific*  *language* (a logic). For the sake of my sanity while debugging, it would be great to be able to type instances of this language (formulas) directly in the toplevel like so:

```
# f = << P(x,y) & x!=y >>
```

Is `campl4/5` my only option? If yes, I find the documentation rather intimidating. Is there an example/tutorial that is close-enough to my use case and that I could conceivably adapt? (For instance, syntax extensions that introduce new keywords do not seem relevant). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to call a function to do the parsing, you can use `ocamlmktop` to include your parser into the top level.  Then you can install printers for your types using `#install_printer`.  The sessions might look like this then:

```
# let x = parse ()
<< type your expression here >>
# x : type = <<formatted version>>
```

I have used specialed printers, and they definitely help a lot with complicated types.  I've never gotten around to using `ocamlmktop`.  I always just load in my code with `#load` and `#use`.

This is a lot easier than mastering camlp4/5 (IMHO).  But maybe it's a bit too crude.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point for a low-maintenance approach. Using a string parser can improve this to almost exactly what I asked for: `# f = parse_str("P(x,y) & x!=y");;`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use camlp4 and it will work reasonably well (including in the toplevel), but no, it's not well-documented, and you will have to cope with that.

For an example that is close to your use-case, see the [Lambda calculus quotation](http://brion.inria.fr/gallium/index.php/Lambda_calculus_quotations) example of the Camlp4 wiki.

For the toplevel, it will work easily. You can dynamically load "camlp4o.cmo" then your syntactic extension in the toplevel, or use [findlib](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/findlib-1.2.1/doc/guide-html/quickstart.html) which handles that: from the toplevel, `#use "topfind";;`, then `#camlp4o;;`, then `#require "myfoo.syntax";;` where `myfoo.syntax` is the name of the findlib package you've created to deploy your extension.